# Порядок слів в перекладі "a collection A of subsets of a set X is said to have"

Tags: from-english

мені потрібно перекласти речення, що містить

> *a collection ''A'' of subsets of a set ''X'' is said to have*.

Поки перекладаю як

> *кажуть, що колекція ''A'' підмножин множини ''X'' має*.

Але мені здається, що це неправильно, тобто *''A''* має стояти наприкінці підречення, -

> *кажуть, що колекція підмножин множини ''X'' ''A'' має*,

але воно тоді не чтається. Як зробити, щоб правильно і читалось зрозуміло? Може потрібні роділові знаки якісь?

Comment: `кажуть, що колекція ''A'' підмножин множини ''X'' має` нормально читається, як на мене.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чому б просто не розписати:

> Нехай  — множина (колекція) підмножин множини X.
>
> Кажуть, що  має <таку-то властивість>, тоді й тільки тоді, коли <виконується певна умова>.

Або:

> Про  — множину (колекцію) підмножин множини X — кажуть, що вона () має <таку-то властивість>, тоді й тільки тоді, коли <виконується певна умова>.

Або:

> Про , що є множиною (колекцією) підмножин множини X, кажуть, що вона () має <таку-то властивість>, тоді й тільки тоді, коли <виконується певна умова>.